# How to transfer woocommerce checkout fields to third party with curl?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am not a good PHP developer so I could use help.
My website is a movie streaming website, the website which handles the subscription payments is found in one domain, and the movie streaming website is found in another domain so when one purchased a yearly or monthly subscription it will redirect to the streaming website so to use the streaming it has to login with email and password they used to pay the subscription so I want to send to the streaming site the user's email and password along with what kind of subscription been purchased from the woo-commerce website.

I used the below code and put it on function.php but nothing is working. Since I am not confident with my PHP knowledge so any guidance will help.`enter code here`

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'redirecting_to_specific_page' );
function redirecting_to_specific_page($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $data = array(
        'body' => array(
        'firstname' => $order->get_billing_first_name(), 
        'lastname' => $order->get_billing_last_name(), 
        'email' => $order->get_billing_email(), 
        'password' => $order->get_account_password(),
        )
    );
    // var_dump($order);
    // echo "what are u doing";
    if( $order->has_status('completed') || $order->has_status('processing') || $order->has_status('paid') || $order->has_status('delivered')){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.habeshaview.tv/api/v1/" . $url . "eaftgg3q4dxwmr492qprppq34rmn43qwotfm");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $server_output;
    }  
}
```

Comment: For starters, there isn't a variable `$url` defined anywhere in the scope of your function.

Comment: sorry, i have that value i just left to post it by mistake. let me know my other mistakes pls